# Help! What's my encoding? ¡××­šwg¿¿uþ}0ã×/Œz0îÏ–þžwóuÜ„

Tags: cipher, computer-puzzle

I wanted to share a wonderful message with all of you lovely people on puzzling.SE, but when I typed it in, all that came out was a string of gibberish:

¡××­šwg¿¿uþ}0ã×/Œz0îÏ–þžwóuÜ„

Thankfully I've changed my keyboard now so I could write this message without any issues. The only problem is, I've forgotten what I was going to say to you all, but I know that it was really uplifting and encouraging. Can someone help me to remember what it was I wanted to say? If you can figure that out, please let me know what happened to my keyboard to make it all go so wrong!

Comment: I'm wondering if this is a garbled URL: `¡××­šwg¿¿...` → `https://...`

Comment: Is the message in english?

Comment: Yes, when it's decoded, the message is in English, and should be clear

Comment: From the look of it, my first instinct is that this puzzle will be (close to) impossible for people that aren't using a Mac.

Comment: @Ian, not true at all. Ashutosh is on the right lines, and you could solve this puzzle by hand if you wanted

Comment: @MattTaylor If possible, could you please share at least one word of minimum 3 char size in the message?

Comment: @MattTaylor I presume you got this issue while sending unicode message from your computer program to sms gateway right? (as sms use either ascii or utf-7)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage Did you by any chance miscount the characters? I see 4 characters in `­šwg` but only 3 characters in `ps:`.

Comment: @kasperd Yes, I did ([one of them is invisible](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MFUeE.png)). It's not a URL anyway :-)

Comment: @AshutoshNigam I'm afraid that this was all contrived, I was brushing up on character encoding and the idea for the puzzle came to mind, wondering what would happen if a 7-bit ascii stream was interpreted as an 8-bit stream, then ANSI gave me a character set in which all of the resulting characters from my stream were uniquely identifiable (which was the reason for using underscores instead of spaces in my message)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solved it :-)

> Besides Unicode, there aren't many character sets that include all of these characters. However, **Windows Latin 1** seems to work. In this encoding, the puzzle text consists of the following character codes (in hexadecimal): `a1 d7 d7 ad 9a 77 67 bf bf 75 fe 7d 30 e3 d7 2f 8c 7a 30 ee cf 96 fe 9e 77 f3 75 dc 84`

---

> The keyboard has two problems. The first one is that it's emitting 7 bits per character instead of 8. When the bits are reassembled in 8-bit chunks, the result is gibberish. I wrote a Python script to reassemble the original text in 7-bit chunks and ended up with `Puzzling_on_stackKqGQC]OK?Sg?Mk\\B` (encouraging, but still 50% garbage)

---

> So the other problem with the keyboard appears to be a loose connection that caused one of these bits to go missing. By adding an extra `1` after bit #119, we can recover the whole message: `Puzzling_on_stackexchange_is_fun!`

---

> Here's my Python script:
>  `thex = 'a1d7d7ad9a7767bfbf75fe7d30e3d72f8c7a30eecf96fe9e77f375dc84'`
>  `tbin = ''.join(bin(int(thex[x:x+2],16))[2:].zfill(8) for x in range(0,len(thex),2))`
>  `tbin = tbin[0:119] + '1' + tbin[119:]`
>  `tplain = [chr(int(tbin[i:i+7],2)) for i in range(0,len(tbin)-1,7)]`
>  `print ''.join(tplain)`

Comment: Impressive! I wonder if there should be a tag for puzzles that involve these computery things like ASCII and Unicode, so that technogumbies like me know not to tackle them :-p

Comment: great, I tried brute force to convert in all encodings getting a few thousand of lines... but failed.... will share code anyway...

Comment: Wow. Didn't expect an answer that quickly! Well done =)

Comment: @randal'thor Excellent suggestion. I'll start a new thread on /meta if you haven't done so already. (Edit: [done](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2876/40))

Comment: Just a note about the 7 bit characters: ASCII was originally a 7 bit encoding.  We like to think in terms of 8 bit bytes these days, so 8 bit ASCII seems 'normal' but it's really the other way around - 8 bit ASCII is weird(and imo should never be used).

Answer (score 2):

I am sure it has to do with mismatched charset, soon going to put actual answer here..

> UTF8 or 64 file read using ascii charset

conversion is giving:

> +AKEA1wDXAK0BYQ-wg+AL8Avw-u+AP4AfQ-0+AOMA1w-/+AVI-z0+AO4AzyATAP4Bfg-w+APM-u+ANwgHg-   not sure if got wrong charset or this is another puzzle...?

Second attempt:

> вобябябйwgвпвпuйн}0бя/илz0йнwu     MIK

using following site for conversion:

> http://www.motobit.com/util/charset-codepage-conversion.asp

My code that did not work :(

```
    $str = "¡××­šwg¿¿uþ}0ã×/Œz0îÏ–þžwóuÜ„";
        $matchArr = array("pass","wchar","byte2be","byte2le","8bit","UCS-2","UCS-2BE","UCS-2LE","UTF-16","UTF-16BE","UTF-16LE","UTF-8","UTF-8-Mobile#DOCOMO","UTF-8-Mobile#KDDI-A","UTF-8-Mobile#KDDI-B","UTF-8-Mobile#SOFTBANK","ISO-8859-1","ISO-8859-2","ISO-8859-3","ISO-8859-4","ISO-8859-5","ISO-8859-6","ISO-8859-7","ISO-8859-8","ISO-8859-9","ISO-8859-10","ISO-8859-13","ISO-8859-14","ISO-8859-15","ISO-8859-16","Windows-1251","CP866","KOI8-R","KOI8-U","CP850"
                );

    foreach($matchArr as $a){
        foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $c){
                    //echo $a. "---".$c. "^". mb_convert_encoding($str,$a, $c)."<br/>";
                    echo $a. "---".$c. "===>". mb_convert_encoding($str,$c, $a)."<br/>";
                }
                echo "-----------------------<br/>";
        }
        /**
        foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $a){
        foreach(mb_list_encodings() as $c){
                echo mb_convert_encoding($str,$a, $c)."<br/>";
        }
    }
   /**/
```

Comment: An i-kratkoe (the backwards N with the curve above it) can only come after a vowel, so that can't be an actual Russian word.